# Ms CRM, deploy from VS alters html files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm-2013

So, I have a html file

```
<html>
  <head>
    ..headstuff..
  </head>
  <body>
    ..bodystuff..
  </body>
</html>
```

This file is included in the package, which I then deploy to my CRM. (rightclick -> deploy)

When I check my deployment, the file is present, and all looks visualy ok. 
But when I check the code it now looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    ..headstuff..
    ..bodystuff..
  </body>
</html>
```

How is this possible?

I've tried changing stuff in CRM and publishing, and it remains the same. I've also tried it with XrmToolbox with only the desired effect. So I'm suspecting the VS-CRM plugin to have something to do with this.

I've also tried different html's, they all get the same treatment.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen issues with the WYSIWYG editor for web resource reformatting HTML incorrectly.  If you're opening the web resource file in the web UI after deploying from VS and allowing the WYSIWYG editor render the content this maybe the issue.